# How to make quarkus multi-module project

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus, multi-module

I have a project:

```
\--- Project ':backend'
     +--- Project ':backend:api'
     \--- Project ':backend:shared'
```

In root module I have configured common dependencies and quarkus plugin
Module API contains services, resources and all needed for web server

Module shared contains repositories and entities

project build successfully, but wroks strangely

Questions:

1. Is it best practice to define common libraries and framework plugin/dependicies between modules
2. Do I correct start a api module to develop new features?
3. How I can fix issue with no stopped server? I want when I start project it works, when I cancel it, it should stop.

Thanks

when I try to start a API with `gradle :backend:api:build :backend:api:quarkusDev`, it works, but after stop a server still running and I can send requests. I think it can be because shared module starts also and after cancel gradle task on api, shared still running. When I try to run again it doesn't work, because port 8080 used, and I need to remove it by 'kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :8080)'

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that splitting into 'shared' and 'api' modules might not be necessary in your case. They appear to be interconnected, forming part of a unified solution within this section of the project. I believe it's more appropriate to divide the business domains into distinct modules—each module dedicated to solving specific problems or addressing particular areas.

I think it's good to define common libraries and framework plugins/dependencies between modules.

Configuring the startup and shutdown of servers should ideally reside in the root, determining what needs to be initiated. When the root is started, all the required modules should begin, and when it's stopped, everything stops. There might be modules in the project that aren't directly linked to the root but handle parallel processes. These could produce artifacts or can be started as a separate project when necessary, necessitating separate completion. However, if modules are interconnected, they should commence from a unified entry point.

Comment: Thanks. I need the separation, because we are developing jobs, which will use entities and repository from api, the main goal why we separate it (reduce duplication of entity and repositories). You mean, that if I have API module with connected shared module, it should run from root via `gradle quarkusDev` instead `gradle :api:quarkusDev` ?

Comment: I understand. Are 'jobs' referring to processes that aren't directly tied to the main project? Would they function as additional modules within the project? If so, could these jobs depend on the main project, incorporating entities and repositories, yet be configured for build to include only necessary components (like common classes) in the job artifact, rather than the entire main project?

Regarding the command 'run from root via Gradle quarkusDev instead of Gradle :api:quarkusDev'—yes, if it aligns with the context or purpose.

Comment: main i mean api + shared

Comment: yes, the jobs should only ingest data from thread party service. I can extend main api and use only needed classes in final job jar to reduce bigger size ?

Comment: Yes. It is certainly possible with maven, but I believe that with gradle there is something similar

Comment: something like:    
**plugins {.   
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.0'   
}.   
    
shadowJar {.   
    // Exclude unwanted dependencies.   
    exclude 'unwanted.group:unwanted-artifact'   
    // Exclude specific packages or classes   
    exclude 'unwanted/package/**'   
}**.